how to run android on qemu
I successfully compiled android12 using aosp, but I don’t know how to run it using qemu
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 2048 -smp 4 -kernel out/target/product/generic_x86_64/kernel-5.10 -initrd out/target/product/generic_x86_64/ramdisk.img -hda out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system.img -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:5555 -show-cursor -serial mon:stdio -device virtio-gpu-pci -append "console=ttyS0 root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=goldfish"
This is the command I ran

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you have a specific need to run Android in QEMU and not use the emulator binary included with AOSP in prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator?
If so...

What command did you use to build AOSP?

What error did you encounter when running with QEMU?

What version of QEMU are you using?

What is your host Linux machine cat /etc/os-release?


Assuming on the other hand you actually just want to start the Android emulator for your build...
You don't need to run QEMU, there is a pre-built emulator binary (based on QEMU) include with AOSP already.
Did you read: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/avd ?
As explained there after building AOSP SDK you just need to run the following command:
$ emulator

If you run emulator --help there is a lot of helpful information.
